# Create Windows 7 Quick Launch

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, icons, quicklaunch

how to Create Windows 7 Quick Launch Icon With C# ?

Comment: Please post more details, perhaps code samples and where you are having difficulties? StackOverflow is not a "give me the code" kind of site.

Comment: Do you mean "how to create a taskbar icon"?

Comment: Quick Lunch Icon? Like a sandwich running really fast? ;)

Comment: Are you asking how to create an icon as a file, or as a resource for an application, or how to add a shortcut to the quick launch folder, etc.?  The question is vague.

Comment: @everyone, I think the question is perfectly clear... a "quick launch icon" is a shortcut in the taskbar's "quick launch" area (next to the Start menu). It used to be a folder in the user's profile, but in Windows 7 it has changed (btw, in most current installers, the feature that tries to create such an icon actually doesn't work in Win7)

Comment: Are you sure he's not talking about a JumpList item?

Comment: @ Thomas Levesqu : I think only you are understood my question !

Comment: @Pedram: The quick launch toolbar was removed in Windows 7.  So it's kinda hard to understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a .lnk file in the c:\users\mumble\appdata\roaming\microsoft\internet explorer\quick launch folder.  Beware that the Quick Launch toolbar is disabled by default in Win7, I don't remember what I did to re-enable it.

Creating the .lnk file takes secret sauce as well.  You can find sample code in my answer in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/9e23a82c-8bed-4b96-8b9a-4c2b6136a622/).