# How to place a shortcut in Windows 7 Quick Launch Bar using C# code

Tags: c#, windows, shortcut, quicklaunch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Windows 7 Quick Launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619355/create-windows-7-quick-launch)

Is there any method to place a shortcut (lnk file) in the quick launch bar of windows 7 using C# code?  The method I used for Win XP doesn't work for Win7:

```
string strAllUsersAppData = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA"); 
string strQuickLaunch = strAllUsersAppData;
strQuickLaunch += @"\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch";
//then i used a method to copy the lnk file in the strQuickLaunch path
```

I don't know how to create the path for it in Win7. Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [this CodeProject page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185512/Programmatically-PIN-shortcut-onto-Taskbar-on-Win7); I realize its not C#; however, read the Background paragraph to understand a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for the link :) i looked also over it. As i read in other articles also, it seems that the path for the Quick launch folder is : C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar. I tried to copy a lnk file in it, but the shortcut don't appear. I am also wondering if the path implies the Username, will it be visible for All Users? I am interested for all users to see them.